# Reverted all my commits on branch still getting conflicts on rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-revert, git-merge-conflict

I was working on a feature branch so long because of sick leave that the `origin/develop` branch is way out of sync with my `feature` branch.

Since I had a small amount of changed rows but in many classes, I decided to just revert all my changes in that `feature` branch, push and then rebase `origin/develop` to my `feature` branch to avoid human error in solving the conflicts on multiple classes and just add my changes manually after it.

Then I checked out to `origin/develop`, ran `git pull`, checked back to my `feature` branch and ran `git rebase origin/develop`.

That rebase still has conflicts with my branch. How is this possible and what should I do to get to my original goal? To have a clean slate on the `feature` branch to safely get all the changes from `origin/develop`?

I get this in git bash:

```
Patch failed at 0001 DEV-1234 Initial commit
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
```

So it apparently gets the conflicts in the initial commit and doesn't get to the reverted state yet at that point. Should I just skip that commit with `git rebase --skip`?

Or, as I'm OK with not having ANY of my changes on the branch left at this point, I can just skip the initial commit AND the reverting commit on my branch so the rebase just cleans the slate by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in my case, **as I didn't want any of my changes being left in my feature branch** I could just rebase origin/develop into my feature branch and just skip all my commits in that rebase. No conflicts and a clean slate. I repeat, do this ONLY if you WANT to get rid of your changes in that branch.